# How to configure docker proxy?

Tags: docker

First of all, I have configured the file /etc/systemd/docker.service/http-proxy:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPKN9.png)

And after that I also added the proxies directions to file /etc/sysconfig/docker.

But when I check with sudo systemctl show --property Environment docker, no environment appears:

root@PR375:/etc/sysconfig# sudo systemctl show --property Environment docker
Environment=

I have followed the newx guide for it https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ and https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-configure-docker-to-use-proxy/

Comment: Please do not post [screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors), and instead paste them inside a code block.

Comment: Also, seems like you created a file in a directory different from what the tutorial specified. The directory should be `docker.service.d`

Comment: I have created the file in the route /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d with the name http-proxy.conf, without success.